# Is it possible to pass all physical audio device to a RDP session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

It seems like when I RDP only the default device is used in REMOTE AUDIO on the device selection on the RDP server.  I have several audio device and I want to redirect them all it that something that is possible?